# The Updated Ubuntu Software Center Doesn't Work 16.04

Tags: updates, software-center, 16.04

I have just updated my Ubuntu to 16.04. Everything is perfect as expected. 
The only thing is, the updated Ubuntu Software Center doesn't function.

[image]

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: probably related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/761745/gnome-software-on-ubuntu-16-04-doesnt-work-gnome-software7052

Comment: It's just a *lazy* software, just like the old Software Center. The truth is it needs to read (or update) a pretty large database upon each start. Sure, that database could be optimized by eliminating the graphics & pictures, resulting in pretty dull simple text items. But no newbie could deal with such interface. It's the graphics loading what makes for the delay.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem.Then I got solution by installing the previous Ubuntu Software Center.
Open terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) then type following command and hit Enter.

```
    sudo apt install software-center
```

After installation, search for Ubuntu Software Center in dashbox using Super key. You can now install apps with ease.