# gnome-software on Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't work

Tags: 16.04, software-center, gnome-software

After plain installation of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS `gnome-software` doesn't work.
It has opened once with GUI, but installation of Unity Tweak Tool didn't finish.

When starting again, GUI doesn't come up.
When opening from terminal, a warning appears, but the application GUI doesn't open.

```
$ gnome-software
(gnome-software:7052): Gs-WARNING: failed to open plugin /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so: /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Does anybody have same experience, and eventually, a solution?

---

According to the recommendation:

```
$ dpkg-query -S /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so
gnome-software: /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so
```

Proposed reinstall of gnome-software did not help.

---

As workaround, use Synaptic Package manager and command line.

Comment: What's the output of `dpkg-query -S /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so`? It should show one or more packages to which this file belongs; hopefully it's `gnome-softwarecenter` or something like that. Can you please reinstall that package with `sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall <PACKAGE_NAME>` and tell me if that helps? Include any error messages in your question that you encounter in the process.

Comment: i have the same problem as you do; and it manifests itelf also the way described in this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/761487/the-updated-ubuntu-software-center-doesnt-work-16-04

Comment: The output as described is:
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
xxxxx:~$ dpkg-query -S /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
gnome-software: /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so

Comment: There is a workaround by using Synaptic Package Manager and command line. Nevertheless, the software center is not working.

Comment: Software Center is still not working: getting this from terminal now!:
(gnome-software:2915): Gs-WARNING **: failed to open plugin /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so: /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

Comment: After having tried every trick, including removing and re-installing gnome software and software center I still cannot open gnome center, getting the same warning about the /usr/lib plugin. I have the english version of ubuntu 16.04, installed over ubuntu 15.10.My husband did the same with the german version - his gnome software is working perfectly despite the fact that he gets in the terminal when entering gnome-software the identical warning about /usr/lib plugin.

Comment: I am using 17.04 on Lenovo X1 Carbon, but this [bug report and solution (#1606238)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1606238) worked for me so far. Will report back if there are issues.

Answer (score 15):

Seen this fix going around, it worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove gnome-software
sudo apt-get install gnome-software
```

It appears if you just reinstall gnome-software it just works!

Comment: right - good solution !

Answer (score 15):

**Perform these steps to Fix gnome-software/ubuntu-software**

Rename or remove the `~/.local/share/gnome-software`.  In the steps below it's removed and will be recreated when you start gnome-software.  It currently has a list of what has been installed.
The first line will ensure the locked up instances are removed from memory.  Might not be necessary.

```
$ killall gnome-software
$ rm -r ~/.local/share/gnome-software
```

Now run `ubuntu-software` or `gnome-software` from the Unity Launch Button.

Comment: This >> :thumbs-up:

Comment: After many installs and attempts, only your solution works, thanks!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I had to go into file manager as root

```
sudo -H nautilus
```

Then move all the files from `/usr/lib/gs-plugins-9` to a temp folder and delete `...reviews.so`

I then opened gnome-software and it loaded empty.

Moved all the `.so` files back and opened successfully to install new software again finally!

Comment: `gksu nautilus` is better command since it is not recommend that you handle GUI applications with `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

I too got this error. 
I did

```
$ ps -aux | grep gnome-software
```

and found that there was already a process running. 
(I believe this may be because I had tried to invoke it from the launcher and it had failed, but that much is a hunch.)

I killed the process. 
I then ran gnome-software again in the terminal and got:

```
(gnome-software:6912): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered
```

(This may be the real reason it had failed but left a process running.)

I then did:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ apt-get install -f --reinstall gnome-software
```

The icon on the launcher now works and brings up the new software centre.

Comment: I'm sorry but your reinstall do not work anymore ! Getting this again:
(gnome-software:2915): Gs-WARNING **: failed to open plugin /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so: /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: @Professor-Quatschny says: After having tried every trick, including removing and re-installing gnome software and software center I still cannot open gnome center, getting the same warning about the /usr/lib plugin. I have the english version of ubuntu 16.04, installed over ubuntu 15.10.My husband did the same with the german version - his gnome software is working perfectly despite the fact that he gets in the terminal when entering gnome-software the identical warning about /usr/lib plugin.

Answer (score 0):

the installation of lubuntu software center (over synaptic or with terminal and
sudo apt install lubuntu-software-center 
worked for me - at least I have now one working software center.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Glad this worked for you. In this case, the OP is aware there are workarounds, but they are specifically looking for a fix for `gnome-software`.