# /boot/efi taking time to mount causing a longer boot time

Tags: boot, mount, uefi

I got my laptop from my company. At first it used to boot like within seconds, but suddenly it started to boot slowly. I searched many solutions. One of them was checking which task is taking the most time during boot. I found the culprit, but unfortunately I couldn't find any solutions to solve it. What should I do to make Ubuntu boot faster like before? Below attached is the image from boot.

[image]

Edit 1:
After reading this article: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/05/fix-slow-boot-ubuntu-18-04/
I found that /boot/efi is taking time to load based on the uuid.

Then I tried to find the if my BIOS power management has some issues like mentioned in one of the answers here:[Why my ubuntu 16.04 LTS suddenly become very slow?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/869500/why-my-ubuntu-16-04-lts-suddenly-become-very-slow)

But nothing, So today morning I changed the boot process to Miminal which was Through before in POST Behavior in my BIOS

My laptop is Dell latitude 3400

Comment: Please update your question with what you tried to solve it.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, I have updated my question.

Comment: This has reminded me to a thread from yesterday: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314356/different-boot-experience-after-cloning-ssd do you find anything helpful in it?

Comment: Nope, I did find that one my uuid doesn't have a path but not solved