# Different boot experience after cloning SSD

Tags: ssd, ubuntu-gnome, clone

I use to have Ubuntu installed on a 64gb SSD... But then it needed more capacity.

So I cloned the SSD into one with 128gb capacity using the "Disks" application on Ubuntu (that comes pre-installed when you use the Ubuntu live boot (from usb in my case))

Now when I boot up, I get a screen I didn't get before and have to wait a few more minutes than normal. The screen I get is:
[image]

If I press the "del" (delete) button, it shows some details about what it's doing:
[image]

I don't know what this means and it would be helpful is someone could explain this behaviour and how to fix it.

(After waiting a few more minutes, the computer boots up as normal and working as expected. The SSD is successfully cloned)

update 1:

my `/etc/fstab` file looks like:

```
~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=6b1b7475-bcd1-426b-b60d-5488f952ef1a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=bcd1-426b  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile
```

the output of the command `sudo lsblk -o UUID,NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,MODEL` is:

```
~$ sudo lsblk -o UUID,NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,MODEL
[sudo] password for user: 
UUID                                 NAME   FSTYPE     SIZE MOUNTPOINT                   LABEL MODEL
                                     loop0  squashfs 143.8M /snap/code/52                      
                                     loop2  squashfs  15.3M /snap/deno/15                      
                                     loop3  squashfs  55.4M /snap/core18/1944                  
                                     loop4  squashfs 217.9M /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60           
                                     loop5  squashfs   219M /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66           
                                     loop6  squashfs 163.3M /snap/gitkraken/167                
                                     loop7  squashfs 149.8M /snap/code/53                      
                                     loop8  squashfs 161.1M /snap/gitkraken/168                
                                     loop9  squashfs 125.9M /snap/docker/471                   
                                     loop10 squashfs  97.9M /snap/core/10577                   
                                     loop11 squashfs  64.4M /snap/gtk-common-themes/1513       
                                     loop12 squashfs  95.8M /snap/rpi-imager/137               
                                     loop13 squashfs  95.8M /snap/rpi-imager/150               
                                     loop14 squashfs  31.1M /snap/snapd/10707                  
                                     loop15 squashfs  97.9M /snap/core/10583                   
                                     loop16 squashfs  64.8M /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514       
                                     loop17 squashfs    51M /snap/snap-store/518               
                                     loop18 squashfs    51M /snap/snap-store/498               
                                     loop19 squashfs  31.1M /snap/snapd/10492                  
                                     loop20           55.5M /snap/core18/1988                  
                                     sda             223.6G                                    CT240BX500SSD1
174D-C0A1                            ├─sda1 vfat       512M                                    
                                     ├─sda2              1K                                    
6b1b7475-bcd1-426b-b60d-5488f952ef1a └─sda5 ext4     223.1G /                                  
                                     sdb             465.8G                                    WDC_WDS500G2B0A-00SM50
C0FB-211B                            ├─sdb1 vfat       100M                                    
                                     ├─sdb2             16M                                    
C27AFBDE7AFBCD63                     ├─sdb3 ntfs     465.2G                                    
1A20494E20493255                     └─sdb4 ntfs       505M
```

i see that there is no match for `bcd1-426b`.

Comment: First of all, create a copy of this `/etc/fstab` file as it is now, and place it somewhere where you will find it later. Just in case you need to restore changes. Also, I would prepare an Ubuntu live USB device and made sure that the machine can be booted from it. If you make a mistake editing `/etc/fstab` it may appear to break the system. No problem. With a working Live USB device and the safety backup copy of the file, you can undo any changes and return the system to its current state.

Comment: Wow, it surprises me that the system could even boot without a correctly referenced EFI partition... (but I'm not a big shot in Linux, so I'm easy to surprise :) )

Comment: im still being cautious about what im doing here, do you think the correct entry in the `/etc/fstab` for `bcd1-426b` should be `174D-C0A1`?

Comment: Look, `bcd1-426b` is a subset of the other, sda5's UUID! What does that mean? I don't know, this is over my head too...

Comment: Yeah, I don't know. Let's hope someone comes who knows Linux and helps you out! :)

Comment: thats because i manually changed it before uploading.... maybe i shouldnt have. in reality it isnt a subset of the other.

Comment: In that case, I would go back to plan A: make a safety copy before editing, make sure that you can boot from your Live USB and in the "Try Ubuntu" session you can mount the right `/` system partition (where this `/etc/fstab` file belongs), and that you will be able to copy back the backup file if needed. After you have insured yourself as such, you could just edit it as you find it makes sense.

Comment: Also, what is that lone `/swapfile` entry? Is that right so? I have not seen such before. (But it's not in my job description, so I'm excused not knowing :) )

Comment: im not sure either... if it help the current computer setup is with 2 separate ssd. (one with window, another with linux). i boot up to a different OS from the motherboard bios. i dont think that would create a swapfile... but maybe it does? it could also be some sideffect of the cloning from another SSD.

Comment: Look at your screenshot again, at the line on the bottom with the red mark, waiting on the timeout: it seems to contain a UUID. That's the wrong one; it's in fstab. That's the one you need to update, I believe.

Comment: After a successful boot, open the "Logs" app, and look for system logs (It also has a tab for just the "Important" log messages). Or look for system logs in any way you know of. My point is the system might have missed something and have fallen back to a fallback. If this is the case, hopefully something about it is written in the logs. If you find it, you are that much better informed.

Comment: Your swap file entry should be like this: `/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0` or did you just not copy last part? Also you are not booting with old drive still plugged in? You cannot have duplicate UUIDs & GUIDs. Not sure if gpt correctly copied. Post this also, if it shows any errors. `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` Concern is if clone moved backup partition table to end of drive where it must be.

Comment: you are correct about about the part when the `/swapfile` line was copied... i think i must have missed it out when copying and pasting to this thread. the old ssd is not connected to the machine... but thats good to know that it isnt an option for them to both have the same uuid in the same machine. the solution is as @levente suggested and updating the uuid in the fstab file from `bcd1-426b` to `174D-C0A1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My wild guess is that it might be trying to mount an additional drive or partition that is not there, and it is waiting for a timeout.

Look at the `/etc/fstab` file and try to spot items there that you think are not valid. In case of doubt, feel free to amend your question.

Update:

I'm almost certain that the unique IDs of disks or partitions are different now than what your cloned system used to use.

The following command will reveal the current UUIDs of disks and partitions:

```
sudo lsblk -o UUID,NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,MODEL
```

You might need to update the problematic entry in `/etc/fstab` with its current UUID.

Answer (score 0):

It is a lame way, but I  had similiar issue.
I run Ubuntu LiveCd and then Grub-repair.
I followed the instructions in here:
https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/