# Cannot install Google Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04 - authentication issue?

Tags: google-chrome, netflix

When I download Google Chrome and then click on install, it seems to time out. I never see the authentication box. How can I fix this? It worked when I ran Ubuntu 16.04 from a memory stick.

Answer (score 2):

There are many post with issues of the new Ubuntu Software app.  I have problems with it on many of my installations... somewhere around two out of five.

The workaround is to install deb packages from the Terminal.

**The Command Line option to install a downloaded deb package**

Go to the directory where you Downloaded the package (`~/Downloads`) and install using the `dpkg -i` command.  Run these steps.  The '$' is the cli prompt.

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
$ sudo apt install -f
```

You can type `ls *deb` to see the list of the files to ensure you are spelling it correctly.

The provided step will resolve the issue you are having with the Chrome deb install, plus other issues with the new **Ubuntu Software** application.

In the case of the downloaded **Google Chrome dep** package, once installed using `dpkg -i` the `google-chrome.list` is automatically added to the `/dev/apt/souces.list.d` which will provide automatic checks and updates for newer versions.

The cli steps above will work as an alternative of other downloaded **deb** packages when having issues with the **Ubuntu Software** application.

**The Ubuntu Software issue**

The GUI resolution can be resolved with:
[gnome-software on Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/a/826208/29012)

Comment: This solution unfortunately may not work properly, because Google Chrome needs to have dependencies such as `libappindicator1` and `libindicator7` (and eventually also `libpango1.0-0`) installed. Using the dpkg installation method will not install the necessary dependency packages automatically. :)

Comment: `sudo apt install -f` should fix it.

Comment: @cl-netbox @pilot6  Thanks! I didn't originally include the `sudo apt install -f` because when running the dep package you will be prompted to continue with the `install -f`.  It appeared obvious.  I updated my answer to include that, plus other important information related to **deb** package installs.  I thought about adding the information to fix the **ubuntu-software** but that is mentioned so many times in this forum, that I didn't some redundancy for the sake of focus on the immediate issue.

Comment: You're welcome @L.D.James ! :) Mainly I mentioned it because many users do not really understand the information they receive after running the command ... mostly they just expect the installation to finish without further interactions and then they immediately want to start using the installed application. :)

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable solution to install Google Chrome, important : it has to be the **64-bit edition of Ubuntu** ! (read more about the topic [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724093/no-more-updates-for-google-chrome-apt-get-update-error/724170#724170)) ... open a terminal and execute these four commands :

```
echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt install google-chrome-stable
```

All necessary packages that are needed as dependency will get installed alongside automatically. Google Chrome will get updated to a newer version automatically when you upgrade the system.