# cannot install any packages in Ubuntu 16.04 - broken dependencies

Tags: package-management, dpkg, dependencies, libreoffice

I have tried all solutions I can find on this site - i cannot even install Synaptics, software center shows no entries.  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade gives me error :-

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libreoffice-core : Breaks: libreoffice-writer (< 1:5.3.1-0ubuntu1~xenial0) but 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial1 is installed
 libreoffice-writer : Depends: libreoffice-base-core (= 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial1) but 1:5.3.1-0ubuntu1~xenial0 is installed
                      Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial1) but 1:5.3.1-0ubuntu1~xenial0 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

assuming this is Libreoffice program I have tried :-

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
sudo apt-get install -f
```

I can not even view installed packages in Software Center....

I have tried everything I can find apart from a complete Ubuntu re-install

Please can anyone help

Thanks guys

Comment: Thanks for the edit - sorry but I simply copied and pasted from terminal I did not notice the incorrect formatting is there special formatting in a post to identify it as code - thanks

Comment: You're very welcome.  You'll find the formatting tool panel just above where you type in (or edit) your question.  To format the code, highlight the code, then hit the format tool **`{}`**.  You can also hit the **`?`** mark or click on **`advanced help`** under the question mark for more formatting tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having problems because of your packages and libraries and repositories are not fully upgraded/updated.

With time they will eventually be updated and upgraded automatically.  You can do this manually when you are installing a package by performing these steps:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt full-upgrade
$ sudo apt autoremove
```

You may have to cycle through those steps more than once to have an absolute clean output.  If the output isn't clean the output will include the necessary steps to fix the errors problems that persist.

Some of the upgrades may require a system reboot to take effect.  You can check if this is the case with this command:

```
$ ls /var/run/*reboot* | egrep -v crond
```

No output will indicate you don't have to reboot.

By the way, you were on the right track about removing the broken packages.  But in this case, that part will unlikely be needed.  The system's upgrade will resolve the depencies.

Comment: Went round in circles a few times with same error but finally addind -f to the sudo apt upgrade worked, but still cannot open software center, do any installs from there

Comment: That's exactly what I was specifying in my answer.  The cycles fixed the problem and gave you the `-f` results (which were your using before performing needed cycles.  The `-f` would not work without the upgrades.   You might consider Upvoting the answer and possibly contribute back to the community by check marking the answer as accepted.  This way others who are stuck can benefit by seeing a workable resolution.

Comment: consider it done!!!

Comment: The software center is very problematic since  it changed in Ubuntu 16.04.  Use [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/826208/29012) to fix it.

Comment: Great! Happiness is having an error free system!