# Ubuntu Software Center does not work Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: software-installation, software-center

I´m completely new to Linux and Ubuntu and I tried to install chrome. But when I tried to open the .deb file with the Ubuntu Software App it did not work. When I open the app manually it won´t load the icons, it´s showing just three gray points.

[That´s what I see when I open the Sofware Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyZxZ.png)

My problem is, that I can open it (and all solutions in the internet seem to be if you can not open it), but I can´t even see what software I could install. The start menu is there and seems to be normal, but if I want to choose a category this appears and if I try to install a special software it just loads and loads and loads...

So, I tried sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb, but I got an error that because of dependency-problems the file can not be configurated.

I hope somebody knows what I did wrong or missed to do and can help me,
thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gnome-software on Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761745/gnome-software-on-ubuntu-16-04-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 alternative ways to install .deb files.

**1)Using Gdebi**

This is a GUI application that handles with installing .deb files to the system. You can download it using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

After you installed the app simply go to the application that you want to install, right click and choose "open with Gdebi" by using Open with option.

**2)Using terminal**

You can always install downloaded .deb files by using:

```
sudo dpkg -i yourprogram.deb
```

Be carefull that you need to be on your directory that .deb file is located. You can right click in file manager and choose the option "open Terminal here".

With that you automatically get to the directory in the terminal and you only will need to copy&paste the command I wrote it.
Try these methods and give us feedback that your problem is solved.

Comment: OK, I tried option one. The window of Gdebi opened and I got an error at status which I was able to fix, but now I got another one: dependency not realizable: gconf-service
What does that mean? And how can I fix that?

Comment: @LuaMia Do you have a good Internet connection ? Other topics related to this problem says that you have to download the dependencies even that you're installing .deb files offline.